# Where are global, minimum and/or maximum values of functions applied to in reality?

Tags: functions

So, where are global, minimum and/or maximum values of functions applied to in reality (other than business modeling/projection, and control of heat environment?

Please give some cool examples of their use in real life.

Thanks!

Comment: "Control of heat environment"? That sounds like a remarkably specialized application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, I can give one basic example. Suppose we wish to maximize the range $R$ of a projectile fired from level ground. If we fire the projectile at an initial speed of $v_0$ and an angle $0^\circ< \theta < 90^\circ$, the time it will spend in the air is given by $$t = 2 \cdot \frac{v_0 \sin \theta}{9.8}$$ and so

$$R \propto \sin \theta \cdot \cos \theta = \frac 12 \sin(2\theta)$$ which achieves a maximum at $\theta = 45^\circ$.

Though this makes a number of assumptions, it does mathematically validate our intuition.